# Angular 2 - Reactive Form Asynchronous Validation w/ Microservice

Tags: forms, angular, validation, asynchronous, angular2-forms

Been thinking of implementing an asychronous [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation) for a form with the sole purpose of communicating with a microservice to extract information out of a person's ID number (like age, date of birth, gender, race, etc) and of course whether the ID number is valid or not based on the country they send through.

So if a person enters their ID number and selects a country, a request is fired off to a microservice, and if they haven't set their gender for instance, it automatically populates it, to which they can change it afterwards if need be.

**Questions**

1. Is it good/OK practice to set other form control values in a validator according to the following scenario?
2. If so, how would I go about modifying the other form control values?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: A validator should never set any values of a form, it should only validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, a validator should never set or update a value of a form control, group or array. It should only validate.

What you can do however is use the `.valueChanges` to listen to changes to the form, and in the callback check if a certain control is valid or not, updating some other control accordingly.

Here's an example:

```
this.form.get('someControl').valueChanges(() => {

  if (this.form.get('someControl').valid) {
    this.form.get('someOtherControl').setValue(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it documented somewhere that it's frowned upon to add logic like this in a validator, since it's a pretty unusual scenario? It does make sense that you seperate the logic completely though, will probably 
 end up marking your answer as correct

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but the name itself makes it pretty clear. And I think it's mentioned somewhere in the official style guide that you should create "pure" functions, meaning that they don't have any side effects. A validator function that modifies some other control would break that pattern, therefore it should only validate and then you would do the other thing somewhere else.

Comment: Yea makes sense, thanks for the prompt feedback mate :)

Comment: Glad to help :)